# IdentityServer - Configuring ApiResources

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, duende-identity-server

So I was following the quick starts from the latest IdentityServer/Duende official resources.

From what I understood, An Api Resource is essentially logical grouping of apiscopes and identityscopes.
You can Have 3 ApiScopes "apiscope1", "apiscope2","apiscope3", wrapped in an ApiResource "api".

When setting the client, you need to specify "api" in scopes, which will automatically give you apiscope1, apiscope2, apiscope3.

**1. Is this correct?**

I have two Apis:
MyApi and IdentityServerApi.

MyApi is configured as follows:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        var idsvrConfig = builder.Configuration.GetSection("IdentityServer").Get<IdentityServerConfiguration>();

        options.Authority = idsvrConfig.Authority;
        options.ClientId = idsvrConfig.ClientId;
        options.ClientSecret = idsvrConfig.ClientSecret;
        options.ResponseType = idsvrConfig.ResponseType;
        options.Scope.Clear();
        //options.Scope.AddRange(idsvrConfig.Scopes);
        options.Scope.Add("openid");
        options.Scope.Add("profile");
        options.Scope.Add("verification");
        options.Scope.Add("apiResource"); //<-------Doesn't work when this is specified!!

        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = idsvrConfig.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint;
        options.SaveTokens = idsvrConfig.SaveTokens;
        foreach (var claims in idsvrConfig.ClaimActionsMapJsonKey)
        {
            options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(claims.Key, claims.Value);
        }
    });
```

Now for the Identity Server API Configuration:

```
var apiResources = new List<ApiResource>()
{
    new ApiResource()
    {
        Name = "apiResource",
        DisplayName ="ApiResource",
        Scopes = new string[] {"test" }
    }
};


var apiScopes = new List<ApiScope>()
{
    new ApiScope()
    {
            Name = "test",
    }
};

var identityResources = new List<IdentityResource>
{
    new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
    new IdentityResources.Profile(),
    new IdentityResource()
    {
        Name = "verification",
        UserClaims = new List<string>
        {
            JwtClaimTypes.Email,
            JwtClaimTypes.EmailVerified
        }
    }
};


var clients = new List<Client>
{
    // interactive ASP.NET Core Web App
    new Client
    {
        ClientId = "api",
        ClientSecrets = { new Secret(){
            Value = "supersecretpass"
        }},

        AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,

        // where to redirect after login
        RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:44330/signin-oidc" },

        // where to redirect after logout
        PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:44330/signout-callback-oidc" },

        AllowedScopes = new List<string>
        {
            IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
            IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
            "verification",
            "apiResource",
            "test"
        }
    }
};


// Add Identity Server services
builder.Services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddInMemoryClients(clients)
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(identityResources)
    .AddInMemoryApiScopes(apiScopes)
    .AddInMemoryApiResources(apiResources)
    //.AddInMemoryClients(builder.Configuration.GetSection("IdentityServer:Clients"))
    //.AddInMemoryIdentityResources(builder.Configuration.GetSection("IdentityServer:IdentityResources"))
    //.AddInMemoryApiScopes(builder.Configuration.GetSection("IdentityServer:ApiScopes"))
    //.AddInMemoryApiResources(builder.Configuration.GetSection("IdentityServer:ApiResources"))
    .AddTestUsers(TestUsers.Users);
```

**2. Why is it that when on MyApi I add the scope "apiResource", I get an invalid scope screen error but when I remove it from the scopes requested by the client the full login/logout flow works?**

Any help/insight is appreciated.

Just in case the versions make any difference, I'm running the following packages:

Both Api are running .NET 7

For MyApi: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect 7.0.5

For Idsvr: Duende.IdentityServer 6.2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the `Scope` containing the `apiResource` field in the client, but did not configure it in the server, `Invalid scope` is caused because the `Scope` cannot match.

You need to specify `apiResource` in `AllowedScopes` of `Client` in `IdentityServerApi`:

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "api",
    ClientSecrets = { new Secret(){
        Value = "supersecretpass"
    }},

    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,

    // where to redirect after login
    RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:44330/signin-oidc" },

    // where to redirect after logout
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:44330/signout-callback-oidc" },

    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
    {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
        "verification",
        "apiResource"
    }
}
```

Then you add the scope `apiResource` in `MyApi`, you should be able to successfully run.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
})
.AddCookie("Cookies")
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
{
    options.Authority = "<idsvr-url>";

    options.ClientId = "api";
    options.ClientSecret = "supersecretpass";
    options.ResponseType = "code";

    options.Scope.Clear();
    options.Scope.Add("openid");
    options.Scope.Add("profile");
    options.Scope.Add("verification");
    options.Scope.Add("apiResource");
    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

    options.SaveTokens = true;
});
```

For more details about `ApiResource` and `ApiScope`, you can refer to [this link](https://nestenius.se/2023/02/02/identityserver-identityresource-vs-apiresource-vs-apiscope/).

**Update:**

The scopes added in `AllowedScopes` should be defined. You only defined `test` in `apiScopes`, not `apiResource`.

```
var apiScopes = new List<ApiScope>()
{
    new ApiScope()
    {
        Name = "test",
    },
    //add this
    new ApiScope
    {
        Name = "apiResource"
    },
};
```

Regarding the "Aud" claim, you don't need to manually configure it. When you add an `ApiResource` and specify the corresponding `Scope`, when the client uses this `Scope` to make a request, the obtained `Token` will have the `Aud` claim by default.

For example, I added two `ApiResources` and specified the corresponding `Scope`:

```
new List<ApiResource>
{
    new ApiResource()
    {
        Name = "apiResource",
        DisplayName ="ApiResource",
        Scopes = new string[] {"test" }
    },
    new ApiResource()
    { 
        Name = "paymentApi",
        DisplayName = "PaymentApi",
        Scopes= new string[] {"test2"}
    }
};
```

Then add the corresponding `Scope` in `ApiScope`:

```
new List<ApiScope>
{         
    new ApiScope()
    {
        Name = "test"
    },
    new ApiScope
    {
        Name = "apiResource"
    },
    new ApiScope
    { 
        Name = "test2"
    }
};
```

Configure `Client` in `IdentityServerApi`(I'm not sure whether your `ClientSecrets` can be verified, because I configured it according to the [official document](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/quickstarts/1_client_credentials/#define-client)):

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "web",
    ClientSecrets = { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },

    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
            
    // where to redirect to after login
    RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:5002/signin-oidc" },

    // where to redirect to after logout
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:5002/signout-callback-oidc" },
    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
     {        
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
        "apiResource",
        "test",
        "test2"
     }
}
```

In ClientApi:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
})
.AddCookie("Cookies")
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
{
    options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";

    options.ClientId = "web";
    options.ClientSecret = "secret";
    options.ResponseType = "code";

    options.Scope.Clear();
    options.Scope.Add("openid");
    options.Scope.Add("profile");
    options.Scope.Add("apiResource");
    options.Scope.Add("test");
    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

    options.SaveTokens = true;
});
```

I can see `.Token.access_token` after successfully logging in with the example built by referring to the [official document](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/quickstarts/):
[image]

Copy this `access_token` and paste in [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/), you can see that your `ApiResource` is included in the `aud`:
[image]

When I add a line in ClientApi:

```
options.Scope.Add("test2");
```

You can see both `apiResource` and `paymentApi` are included in `aud`:
[image]

Comment: I have updated the code to reflect your changes, but still not working.
Thanks also for the link, I did read that actually prior to you referring to it, however it does not show a c# client connecting to idsvr using api resource. Furthermore the post mentions "Aud" claim, and it seems like I am supposed to add this during the request? That made me confused as no identity server documentation mention that I believe. Hence me asking questions 1 and 2 :D

Comment: Hi @Style, I updated my answer, you can check it.

Comment: I think I had this totally the other way round. I was under the impression that if I have an api resource called "A", which has "b" and "c" as scopes, in my client I can then just send a list of scope with just A, and the resulting token would have scopes b and c automatically. 
Am I correct in saying that the actual request should be b and c, and then A shows up in the AUD?

Comment: I have re read that link you sent in your original answer, and I think I finally understood the aim of api resources. The aim is that for example API A (which has corresponding API Resource A with scopes B and C), can request scopes B and C and in the access token the AUD claim is populated. API A can then validate that the AUD is actually A, because if not, the access token used in the current request means that the user has managed to get scope B and C through some other means and isnt valid?

Again thanks for being so patient with me.

Comment: You can understand that if the request sent by the **client** contains one of scopes `B` and `C`, then the Token returned by **IdentityServer** will contain `API Resource A`. `API Resource A` cannot be accessed if it is not included.